# Regex: check if string left of some pivot character is equal to the string right of the pivot

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to write a regex that checks if the left and right part (relative to some pivot character) is equal, e.g.

`m2/m2` -> yes

`m3/m2` -> no

How do I write a regex that checks if a capture on the left side of the pivot character is equal to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
/(\w*)\/\1\b/g
```

This will match the m1/m1 in a string, whatever its size (note that it won't be fooled by m1/m11 but requires a space after the second word).
If your string is only like m1/m1, this is even better:

```
/^(\w*)\/\1$/
```

In C#: `new Regex(@"^(.*?)/\1$")`

Comment: Thank you, added a C# version of the regex.

Comment: @larsm you'd better make your dot [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (`.*?`).

Comment: could you elaborate on why?

Comment: Your `.*` will eat everything. Your regex will be at the end of the string and wonder 'oh I need a \ too', and will go backward until finding one (in a case of a global match, this would be disastrous as you'd first match the last /, then the one before and so on...). A lazy operator would stop at the first /, which is what you want. In your case, performance won't matter, but it's still better to always build regex with performance in mind (that's my opinion though).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the C# syntax, but the following works in Python and perl:

```
([^/]+)/\1
```

The `\1` refers back to the first capture group and matches whatever was captured there.